# Campaign and account reports

Tags: apex, account, joined-reports, campaign

Is it me or everyone face issues when it comes to reporting on accounts from campaign ?

I am trying to see all the accounts related to a campaign

I do not see a report where I can pull campaigns with reports :(

Is there something I am missing ?

Comment: Do you mean Accounts related to Contacts which are added as Campaign Members, or where the the source lead was a member?

Comment: duh!! ok this is what i want. I want to get all tasks related to one or more campaigns related to an account. The account is related through a custom lookup on campaign.

Comment: I also created a custom report type with primary as account and secondary as campaign. not sure how to get the tasks :( I was unable to get by default campaign wth accounts added to all my acccout is private sharing model:(

Comment: If its a custom lookup, I'm guessing it needs a custom report type - Accounts with Campaigns? Duh! Have you created that!?

Comment: yes i did sir :)!! but how to get the tasks related tot e campaigns its more like getting account(1) --> campaigns(10)--> tasks(20) in the same reprt !!

Comment: Okay, I'm wondering if it is more Campaigns with Tasks with a filter on Accounts.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6442/discussion-between-rao-and-techtrekker)

Comment: exactlyyyyy that is wht i want :)

Comment: is it possible to do techtrekker!!!

Comment: i figured it !! wasted so much for such a thing !!!

Comment: Maybe post an answer and mark it as the solution :) (I did eventually get on chat)

Answer (score 1):

So this was my approach

Step 1: Created a lookup between Accounts and Campaigns

Step 2: Created a custom report and related Campaigns with Activities

Step 3: Created a report with custom type 
Challenge : This report filter does not have link to the account__c it has only account.name :(

My requirement was to pass the accountID to the report's pv0 and generate a report
Reason: Conga button passes over the accountID to the report and generates the data on the report.

Solution: conga fortunately lets you pass the pv0 as an optional param :

I passed the accountname to the pv0 of the report = '00OK0000000FaWU' related to the accountID passed to the button by a VF page.

```
https://www.appextremes.com/apps/Conga/Composer.aspx? 
SessionId={!$Api.Session_ID} 
&ServerUrl={!$Api.Partner_Server_URL_210} 
&Id={!Account.Id} 
&TemplateId=a25K0000000D6wF 
&FP0=1 
&ReportId=00OK0000000FaWU?
```

**pv0={!Account.Name}** (do not give the line break here as I did the button will break there should be no line break, I did it to highlight the pv0 part)
    &DS7=13 
    &OCNR=1

If someones wondering about how to pass value to a standard button look below :

Use the URLFOR function and pass the value to the button

button name : Conga_Composer_temp ( not the label)

```
<apex:commandButton value="Export Report"
onclick="openConga()"/>
<Script Language="JavaScript">
function openConga() {
```

**window.open('{!URLFOR($Action.Account.Conga_Composer_temp,Account_Id)}', '','scrollbars=yes,menubar=no,height=800,width=700,resizable=yes, toolbar=no,location=no,status=yes'); }**

```
</Script>
```

Phew !!!! Hope this helps someone who wants to design a custom report using conga :/