# Report on accounts in campaigns

Tags: reporting, account, contact, campaign, campaign-member

This is basically the same question as [Campaign and account reports](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/4481/campaign-and-account-reports), i.e. how to create a report using the objects accounts and campaigns. My understanding is that the following four objects are linked / can be linked:

**accounts > contacts > campaign members > campaigns**

However I was not able to create such a custom report. It was not possible to choose these four objects.

When starting at the campaign as the main object one can choose the campaign member as the second object but is stuck there (not possible to select more related objects).

When starting with the account as the main object one can select the contact object as the related object but from there it's not possible to select the campaign member object as the third related object.

Is this an issue with our set up of Salesforce or is this an generall issue?

The objective is to create a report of the following structure:

```
Account ID | Account Manager | Campaign Member, i.e. the Contact | Campaign  | Campaign End Date | Campaign Member Status
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Company A  | Mr. Smith       |  Ms. Doe                          | Sell more | 31.03.2019        | Contacted
Company A  | Mr. Smith       |  Ms. Jones                        | Inform    | 31.06.2019        | eMail sent
Company B  | Mr. Green       |  Ms. Westminster                  | Sell more | 31.03.2019        | Contacted
Company C  | Mr. Smith       |  Mr. Bond                         | Inform    | 31.06.2019        | Meeting scheduled
```

Answer (score 0):

When I went through my org to try to create a report like you asked the relationships were:

Account > Contact > Campaign **history**

Did you not have this as an option? If not then there is likely some limitation on your edition of Salesforce.

Comment: Yes, this option exists and I have created a report Account > Contact > Campaign history > Campaign member. However this report doesn't seem to do the trick, e.g. when creating a report using the campaign member status, all campaign member status values displayed in the report are all the same (even though there actually are not).

Comment: Can you update your question to be more specific as to what information you are trying to report on? You can't expect 1 report type to deliver everything. Your question specifically states account to campaign which the above report could deliver and even if that was not good enough, a junction object would be. Are you doing accounts to campaigns or accounts to campaign members?

Comment: As I understand there is no direct link between accounts and campaigns (see https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BrEVAA0) and therefore one must add contacts to campaigns which in turn creates the technical object campaign member.

Comment: That doesn't help oliver because you're still not quite grasping what I'm saying or what is said in the answer to the other question you posted. Yes there is no direct relationship so **you have to create the relationship**. That also doesn't answer the question about why you are so focused on campaign members.

Comment: I am so focused on Campaign Members since they hold the information what the status is, e.g. for a cross selling campaign the status of the campaign member shows wheather the offer was made or if the offer was accepted or rejected.